# result.current.data is undefined when I declare renderHook into the test closure but works when it is defined outside of it

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I'm trying to test a custom hook but for some reason I can't render the hook inside the test closure "it".

This code works (I must use the rerender methods otherwise the result.current.data remains undefined) :

```js
describe('useGet hook', () => {

  const { result, rerender, unmount } = renderHook(
    () => useGet<IApplication>(getApplication),
    {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => (
        <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>{children}</AuthProvider>
      ),
    }
  );

  it('should make a GET request and return the data', async () => {
    rerender() 
    console.log(result)

  });
```

This code does not work :

```js
  it('should make a GET request and return the data', async () => {

    const { result, rerender, unmount } = renderHook(
      () => useGet<IApplication>(getApplication),
      {
        wrapper: ({ children }) => (
          <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>{children}</AuthProvider>
        ),
      }
    );
    rerender()
    console.log(result)
  });
```

In both cases I can see that the loader state has changed (false to true) but the data remains undefined

```
   {
      current: {
        data: undefined,
        error: null,
        isLoading: true,
        refetch: [Function: executeCallback]
      }
    }
```

Here is my customhook :

```js
 const useGet = <T,>(
  callbackFn: () => Promise<T | null>,
  onPersist?: (data: T | null) => void,
  onError?: (error: ConnectError | null) => void
): useGetResponseType<T> => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<ConnectError | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const { userData } = useAuth();

  const executeCallback = () => {
    if (!callbackFn) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    return callbackFn()
      .then((dataResponse: T | null) => {
        setData(dataResponse);

        if (onPersist) {
          onPersist(dataResponse);
        }

        return dataResponse;
      })
      .catch((errorResponse: AxiosError<ConnectError>) => {
        setError(errorResponse?.response?.data || null);

        if (onError) {
          onError(errorResponse?.response?.data || null);
        }

        return null;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading || !userData) {
      return;
    }

    executeCallback();
  }, [userData]);

  return {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    refetch: executeCallback,
  };
};
```

Comment: Does the `getApplication` function resolve some data?

Comment: Yes, It return a Promise.resolve : 
const getApplication: () => Promise<IApplication | null> = () =>
Promise.resolve(applicationMockData);

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using https://stackblitz.com/?